# Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentNotFoundException : No component for supporting the service Castle.Services.Transaction.ITransactionManager was found

Tags: asp.net-mvc, fluent-nhibernate, castle-windsor

Hi I am using Castle with the NHibernate Integration Faclility

I am running a few tests and they are failing with the error

```
at Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.get_Item(Type service)
at Castle.Facilities.NHibernateIntegration.DefaultSessionManager.ObtainCurrentTransaction()
at Castle.Facilities.NHibernateIntegration.DefaultSessionManager.OpenSession(String alias)
at Castle.Facilities.NHibernateIntegration.DefaultSessionManager.OpenSession()
at Core.Repositories.NHibernateSqlDbLiteRepository`1.GetAll()
```

Answer (score 1):

well I think the error is pretty obvious - you didn't register transaction manager. This probably means you didn't add Transaction facility to the container, did you?